# Specifying the output file name in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a MapReduce job that I'm trying to migrate to PySpark. Is there any way of defining the name of the output file, rather than getting `part-xxxxx`?

In MR, I was using the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat` class to achieve this,

PS: I did try the `saveAsTextFile()` method. For example:

```
lines = sc.textFile(filesToProcessStr)
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: re.split('[\s&]', x.strip()))\
.saveAsTextFile("/user/itsjeevs/mymr-output")
```

This will create the same `part-0000` files.

```
[13:46:25] [spark] $ hadoop fs -ls /user/itsjeevs/mymr-output/
Found 3 items
-rw-r-----   2 itsjeevs itsjeevs          0 2014-08-13 13:46 /user/itsjeevs/mymr-output/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   2 itsjeevs itsjeevs  101819636 2014-08-13 13:46 /user/itsjeevs/mymr-output/part-00000
-rw-r--r--   2 itsjeevs itsjeevs   17682682 2014-08-13 13:46 /user/itsjeevs/mymr-output/part-00001
```

**EDIT**

Recently read [the article](http://databricks.com/blog/2014/09/17/spark-1-1-bringing-hadoop-inputoutput-formats-to-pyspark.html) which would make life much easier for Spark users.

Comment: how did you imported MultipleTextOutputFormat in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark is also using Hadoop under the hood, so you can probably get what you want. This is how `saveAsTextFile` is implemented:

```
def saveAsTextFile(path: String) {
  this.map(x => (NullWritable.get(), new Text(x.toString)))
    .saveAsHadoopFile[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable, Text]](path)
}
```

You could pass in a customized `OutputFormat` to `saveAsHadoopFile`. I have no idea how to do that from Python though. Sorry for the incomplete answer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. it is definitely some place to start. Will mark this accepted for the time being.

Comment: @Jeevs Did you get how to give the custom name to the output file.

Comment: I have a bit more complete understanding of Hadoop since then. You _could_ do it with a custom `OutputFormat`, but it will be quite a bit of effort. The file names come from fairly deep in the file writing system. I would encourage you to just accept the file names as they are. Perhaps rename them after writing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could get in python to the accepted answer:

```py
def saveAsSingleJsonFile(df, path, filename):
    rdd = df.toJSON()
    rdd.map(lambda x: (None, x)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
        f"{path}/{filename}",
        "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat",
        keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
        valueClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.Text"
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Your output files will look like;

myfilename-r-00000
myfilename-r-00001

```
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WCSYNC-FileCompressor-ClusterSaver");
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf);
            JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sc)
context.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", "myfilename");




saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(outputpath,
                                Text.class,
                                Text.class,
                                TextOutputFormat.class,
                                context.hadoopConfiguration());
```