# spark RDD saveAsTextFile does not use the specified filename

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, rdd

I have some code like this

```
  wordCounts
  .map{ case (word, count) =>
    Seq(
      word,
      count
    ).mkString("\t")
  }
  .coalesce(1,true)
  .saveAsTextFile("s3n://mybucket/data/myfilename.csv")
```

However myfilename.csv was created as a directory in my S3 bucket and the file name is always something like myfilename.csv/part-00000? Is there a way I can change the name of the file I am writing to? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25310729/2706419
you can try this

Comment: Thanks for the link, very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you use the spark-csv package from Databrick to read and write csv files in Spark. One of the (many) benefits from using this package is that it allows you to specify the name of the output csv-file :)

Comment: Thanks Glennie. This is definitely something I will check out (I will mark it as accepted for now).